# How to load a sub function of a function using if/else condition statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load sub function of a function using if/else conditions.The code is as follows.

```
var db,did;
            function loaddb()
            {
                db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2*1024*1024);
                db.transaction(createDB, errorCB, successCB);
            }
            function createDB(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USERIDDETAILS');
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERIDDETAILS (deviceid TEXT NOT NULL)');
            }
            function errorCB(err) {
                alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
                console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
            }
            function successCB() {
                console.log("success");
            }
            function insertDB(tx) {
                did = $("[name='deviceid']").val();
                var sql='INSERT INTO USERIDDETAILS(deviceid)VALUES(?)';
                tx.executeSql(sql,[did],sucessQueryDB,errorCB);
                console.log(did);
            }   
            function sucessQueryDB(tx){
                alert("selected");
                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM USERIDDETAILS',[],renderList,errorCB); 
            }
            function renderList(tx,results){ 
            alert("rendering");
                var htmlstring='';
                var len=results.rows.length;
                alert("rendered called"+ len);
                for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                    htmlstring += '<li>'+ results.rows.item(i).deviceid+'</li>';
                }   
                $('#resultList').html(htmlstring);
                $('#resultList').listview('refresh');
            }

            function onClick(){
                db.transaction(insertDB,errorCB);
                $.ajax({
                    url : "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels.json?api_key=XXXXXXXXXX",
                    dataType:"json",
                    cache: false,
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    debugger;
                            alert(xhr.statusText);
                            alert(thrownError.code);
                        },
                    success : function(json) {
                    console.log("Entering getIdList.success()");
                    console.log(json);
                    alert(json);
                    if (json.length == 0) {
                        window.alert("The returned output array length is ZERO.");
                    } else {
                        var obj, des , md ,apiKeys;
                        //i=channels object length
                        for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
                            obj = json[i];
                            //console.log(obj);
                            if (obj == null || obj == "") {
                                window.alert("\n The "+(i+1)+"th object is NULL/BLANK.");
                            } else {
                                if (obj.id == did) {

                                if (obj.name == null || obj.name == "") {
                                        window.alert("\n The name portion of "+(i+1)+"th object is NULL/BLANK.");
                                    } else {
                                        console.log("\n The deails of "+(i+1)+"th Object are :  \nDname : " + obj.name);
                                        alert("\n The deails of "+(i+1)+"th Object are :  \nDname : " + obj.name);

                                        function dnamedb()
                                        {
                                            db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2*1024*1024);
                                            db.transaction(creatednDB, errorCB, successCB);
                                        }
                                        function creatednDB(tx) {
                                            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEVICENAME');
                                            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEVICENAME(Dname TEXT NOT NULL)');
                                            //alert("done");
                                        }

                                        function insertdnDB(tx){
                                            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEVICENAME(Dname)VALUES(obj.name)');
                                        }

                                        function dnameForm(){
                                            db.transaction(insertdnDB,errorCB);
                                            return false;
                                        }

                                    }
                                }                   
                            }           
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }); 
       <body>
    <div id="header">
        <h3> Login </h3>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            loaddb();
            dnamedb();
            }); 
        </script>
    </div>
    <div id="section">
        <form method="post" id="myForm">
             <br><input type="text" class="one" name="deviceid" id="deviceid" placeholder="DeviceId"><br>
             <input type="button" class="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="return onClick()">
        </form>
    </div>
```

In the above code i have a textfield deviceid and submit button after entering the device id(did) and i click on submit the function onClick() will be done here the url will be loaded and checks the condition if/else whether the did is present in the url are not.If the did is correct it should display the name of the device id and the function dnamedb() should be loaded.I got the name but dnamedb() is not loadingi got an error:Uncaught ReferenceError: dnamedb is not defined.
Can anyone help me??
Thankyou.

Comment: Sorry mate, but it's not real clear what you're asking. Are you getting an error in the Dev Tools console?

Comment: I dint get any error my doudt is how can i load the function dnamedb() if the condition jumps to the else statement in the code @CobusKruger

Comment: Still not getting it. Have you tried calling the function there? If so, what happened? Or is that still not what your're asking?

Comment: I edited the code and the error now i got can u have a look on it.I hope u understand the problem now@CobusKruger

Answer (score 0):

you can not define a function inside ajax success. you can call it there. and define it outside the $.ajax({});

```
         var db,did;
        function loaddb()
        {
            db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2*1024*1024);
            db.transaction(createDB, errorCB, successCB);
        }
        function createDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USERIDDETAILS');
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERIDDETAILS (deviceid TEXT NOT NULL)');
        }
        function errorCB(err) {
            alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
            console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
        }
        function successCB() {
            console.log("success");
        }
        function insertDB(tx) {
            did = $("[name='deviceid']").val();
            var sql='INSERT INTO USERIDDETAILS(deviceid)VALUES(?)';
            tx.executeSql(sql,[did],sucessQueryDB,errorCB);
            console.log(did);
        }   
        function sucessQueryDB(tx){
            alert("selected");
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM USERIDDETAILS',[],renderList,errorCB); 
        }
        function renderList(tx,results){ 
        alert("rendering");
            var htmlstring='';
            var len=results.rows.length;
            alert("rendered called"+ len);
            for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                htmlstring += '<li>'+ results.rows.item(i).deviceid+'</li>';
            }   
            $('#resultList').html(htmlstring);
            $('#resultList').listview('refresh');
        }

        function onClick(){
            db.transaction(insertDB,errorCB);
            $.ajax({
                url : "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels.json?api_key=XXXXXXXXXX",
                dataType:"json",
                cache: false,
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                debugger;
                        alert(xhr.statusText);
                        alert(thrownError.code);
                    },
                success : function(json) {
                console.log("Entering getIdList.success()");
                console.log(json);
                alert(json);
                if (json.length == 0) {
                    window.alert("The returned output array length is ZERO.");
                } else {
                    var obj, des , md ,apiKeys;
                    //i=channels object length
                    for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
                        obj = json[i];
                        //console.log(obj);
                        if (obj == null || obj == "") {
                            window.alert("\n The "+(i+1)+"th object is NULL/BLANK.");
                        } else {
                            if (obj.id == did) {

                            if (obj.name == null || obj.name == "") {
                                    window.alert("\n The name portion of "+(i+1)+"th object is NULL/BLANK.");
                                } else {
                                    console.log("\n The deails of "+(i+1)+"th Object are :  \nDname : " + obj.name);
                                    alert("\n The deails of "+(i+1)+"th Object are :  \nDname : " + obj.name);

                                  dnamedb();                               
                                  creatednDB(tx);        
                                  insertdnDB(tx,obj.name);
                                  dnameForm();


                                }
                            }                   
                        }           
                    }
                }   
            }
        }); 
        function dnamedb()
                                    {
                                        db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2*1024*1024);
                                        db.transaction(creatednDB, errorCB, successCB);
                                    }
                                    function creatednDB(tx) {
                                        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEVICENAME');
                                        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEVICENAME(Dname TEXT NOT NULL)');
                                        //alert("done");
                                    }

                                    function insertdnDB(tx,name){
                                        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEVICENAME(Dname)VALUES("'+ name +'")');
                                    }

                                    function dnameForm(){
                                        db.transaction(insertdnDB,errorCB);
                                        return false;
                                    }
   <body>
<div id="header">
    <h3> Login </h3>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        loaddb();
        dnamedb();
        }); 
    </script>
</div>
<div id="section">
    <form method="post" id="myForm">
         <br><input type="text" class="one" name="deviceid" id="deviceid" placeholder="DeviceId"><br>
         <input type="button" class="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="return onClick()">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with declaring a function within `success`, but you won't be able to call it outside `success`. An important distinction.

Answer (score 0):

`dbnamedb` is defined within your `success` function. That means it is scoped to that function and you can only call it from that function. This is why the name is not defined in `$(document).ready`.

Sudhanshu did a fine job of restructuring your code to a valid configuration, but I should add that adding a horde of functions to the global scope is a bad idea. All your functions will now be accessible from the global `window` object, and the more you do that, the higher the odds of a naming conflict and a hard-to-trace bug.

So instead, I'm going to take Sudhanshu's answer and change it into an immediately-invoked function expression, remove your script tag and took the `onclick` call out of the markup. That gives you the following HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <h3> Login </h3>
</div>
<div id="section">
    <form method="post" id="myForm">
         <br><input type="text" class="one" name="deviceid" id="deviceid" placeholder="DeviceId"><br>
         <input type="button" class="button" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
</div>
```

And JavaScript code that looks like this (and hopefully you place it in an external file, not in the page `head` section):

```
(function () {
    var db, did;

    function loaddb() {
        db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
        db.transaction(createDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    function createDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USERIDDETAILS');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERIDDETAILS (deviceid TEXT NOT NULL)');
    }

    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
        console.log("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
    }

    function successCB() {
        console.log("success");
    }

    function insertDB(tx) {
        did = $("[name='deviceid']").val();
        var sql = 'INSERT INTO USERIDDETAILS(deviceid)VALUES(?)';
        tx.executeSql(sql, [did], sucessQueryDB, errorCB);
        console.log(did);
    }

    function sucessQueryDB(tx) {
        alert("selected");
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM USERIDDETAILS', [], renderList, errorCB);
    }

    function renderList(tx, results) {
        alert("rendering");
        var htmlstring = '';
        var len = results.rows.length;
        alert("rendered called" + len);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            htmlstring += '<li>' + results.rows.item(i).deviceid + '</li>';
        }
        $('#resultList').html(htmlstring);
        $('#resultList').listview('refresh');
    }

    $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function () {
        db.transaction(insertDB, errorCB);
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels.json?api_key=XXXXXXXXXX",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                debugger;
                alert(xhr.statusText);
                alert(thrownError.code);
            },
            success: function (json) {
                console.log("Entering getIdList.success()");
                console.log(json);
                alert(json);
                if (json.length == 0) {
                    window.alert("The returned output array length is ZERO.");
                } else {
                    var obj, des, md, apiKeys;
                    //i=channels object length
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        obj = json[i];
                        //console.log(obj);
                        if (obj == null || obj == "") {
                            window.alert("\n The " + (i + 1) + "th object is NULL/BLANK.");
                        } else {
                            if (obj.id == did) {
                                if (obj.name == null || obj.name == "") {
                                    window.alert("\n The name portion of " + (i + 1) + "th object is NULL/BLANK.");
                                } else {
                                    console.log("\n The deails of " + (i + 1) + "th Object are :  \nDname : " + obj.name);
                                    alert("\n The deails of " + (i + 1) + "th Object are :  \nDname : " + obj.name);
                                    dnamedb();
                                    creatednDB(tx);
                                    insertdnDB(tx, obj.name);
                                    dnameForm();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function dnamedb() {
        db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
        db.transaction(creatednDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    function creatednDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEVICENAME');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEVICENAME(Dname TEXT NOT NULL)');
        //alert("done");
    }

    function insertdnDB(tx, name) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEVICENAME(Dname)VALUES("' + name + '")');
    }

    function dnameForm() {
        db.transaction(insertdnDB, errorCB);
        return false;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        loaddb();
        dnamedb();
    });
})();
```

The `$(document).ready` is moved into the main script body and I wrapped it all in this:

```
(function () {
// Code goes here
})();
```

That is an anonymous function that is declared and immediately executed.

This snippet is taken from the above code, but with all the database access removed. The `onclick` now gives a very fetching message.

```js
(function () {
    var db, did;

    function loaddb() {
        db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
        db.transaction(createDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    function createDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USERIDDETAILS');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERIDDETAILS (deviceid TEXT NOT NULL)');
    }

    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
        console.log("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
    }

    function successCB() {
        console.log("success");
    }

    function insertDB(tx) {
        did = $("[name='deviceid']").val();
        var sql = 'INSERT INTO USERIDDETAILS(deviceid)VALUES(?)';
        tx.executeSql(sql, [did], sucessQueryDB, errorCB);
        console.log(did);
    }

    function sucessQueryDB(tx) {
        alert("selected");
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM USERIDDETAILS', [], renderList, errorCB);
    }

    function renderList(tx, results) {
        alert("rendering");
        var htmlstring = '';
        var len = results.rows.length;
        alert("rendered called" + len);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            htmlstring += '<li>' + results.rows.item(i).deviceid + '</li>';
        }
        $('#resultList').html(htmlstring);
        $('#resultList').listview('refresh');
    }

    $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function () {
      alert('Hello');
        /* This cannot be executed in a StackOverflow snippet
        db.transaction(insertDB, errorCB);
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels.json?api_key=XXXXXXXXXX",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                debugger;
                alert(xhr.statusText);
                alert(thrownError.code);
            },
            success: function (json) {
                console.log("Entering getIdList.success()");
                console.log(json);
                alert(json);
                if (json.length == 0) {
                    window.alert("The returned output array length is ZERO.");
                } else {
                    var obj, des, md, apiKeys;
                    //i=channels object length
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        obj = json[i];
                        //console.log(obj);
                        if (obj == null || obj == "") {
                            window.alert("\n The " + (i + 1) + "th object is NULL/BLANK.");
                        } else {
                            if (obj.id == did) {
                                if (obj.name == null || obj.name == "") {
                                    window.alert("\n The name portion of " + (i + 1) + "th object is NULL/BLANK.");
                                } else {
                                    console.log("\n The deails of " + (i + 1) + "th Object are :  \nDname : " + obj.name);
                                    alert("\n The deails of " + (i + 1) + "th Object are :  \nDname : " + obj.name);
                                    dnamedb();
                                    creatednDB(tx);
                                    insertdnDB(tx, obj.name);
                                    dnameForm();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    */});

    function dnamedb() {
        db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
        db.transaction(creatednDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    function creatednDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEVICENAME');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEVICENAME(Dname TEXT NOT NULL)');
        //alert("done");
    }

    function insertdnDB(tx, name) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEVICENAME(Dname)VALUES("' + name + '")');
    }

    function dnameForm() {
        db.transaction(insertdnDB, errorCB);
        return false;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // These two can't execute within a StackOverflow snippet
        //loaddb();
        //dnamedb();
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
    <h3> Login </h3>
</div>
<div id="section">
    <form method="post" id="myForm">
         <br><input type="text" class="one" name="deviceid" id="deviceid" placeholder="DeviceId"><br>
         <input type="button" class="button" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but i am getting error unexpected token at  first line of the function.                                                                                                function () {
// Code goes here
}();

Comment: @Anusha Sorry, I always forget to surround the function declaration in brackets as well. I'll update the answer.

Comment: tq for the edit now i tried to run now i got an error                         Uncaught ReferenceError: onClick is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Comment: Right. That's because you're referencing `onclick` from the HTML. Not a big problem. Another edit coming up.

Comment: I tried your edited code now the it is just loading the page when i enter the id and click on submit nothing is processing it stoped.

Comment: Any console errors? There must be something wrong with the way you integrated it. I added a snippet that shows it working, although I obviously had to remove the calls to the database (SO doesn't allow those). The base code works; confirm it by running the snippet.

Comment: I dint get any errors when page loads it gave success msg in console tha loaddb() is loaded then i tried giving deviceid and click on submit it dint process further n i dint get any error msg also